# How to mix SSAS with other sources in PowerBi

Tags: ssas, powerbi

Using PowerBi we cannot find any way to mix data coming from SQL Server Analysis Services with other data sources (Excel to make it easy).

As soon as we select the SSAS data source, the new source button is greyed and no way to use it.
Trying the inverse (Excel first) seems to work but importing specific SSAS data (which in our case is several milion rows) so in fact is hardly usable as we have to know in advance what columns are we going to use for every report ... not quite user friendly!

Is there any way to do it the "logical" way?

thks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerBI does not allow to mix DirectQuery with other data sources.

If it fits your task you could use your source in Import mode instead.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-use-directquery/

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the info I needed.